# Is it possible to embed an ActiveXObject into an Adobe AIR application?

Tags: apache-flex, air, activex

Is it possible to embed an ActiveXObject (in this case, the 3DVia Viewer) into an AIR application and communicate with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Its possible.

You have to call Javascript functions from Air into your browser/IExplore and call the ActiveXObject from Javascript. At least thats the way I would do it.

Comment: So, would I embed the ActiveXObject into the actual AIR application,  or embed the ActiveX into a web page and just communicate with IExplore from AIR? I'd prefer a way to control the Active X directly from my ActionScript code. I'm very unsure of how to go about this, so any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Imho, embed is not possible. AIR has mx:HTML control, but it's based on Webkit, not IE. So your option is communicate with web page in IE.

Comment: @alxx : Thanks, that's what I thought, but I wanted it confirmed before telling my project leader...:-)